# How to Collect information from WebSite Into c# array with Selenium?

Tags: c#, html, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to Collect some Specified Numbers into An array in C# with Selenium.
But there is a question!
[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEU5V.jpg) an IMG of Those Numbers!

Every Row is in a `<div>` tag and Every Number is in Another `<div>` tag like This:

```
<div>
     <div>
          Here is The Number!
     </div>
</div>
```

now How Can I Export all Those Numbers Into an Array?

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: @DebanjanB I did not test any code

Comment: How would you conclude which solution works and which doesn't works?

Comment: @Arashmoghadas Refer [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First of all u need to get all Crash rows in list using something like

```
public List<IWebElements> GetAllCrashRows()
{
driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'crash-row crash')]"));
}
```

Once u get all rows in List, u need to get all inner rows using foreach loop:

```
public List<IWebElement> GetAllRows(){
List<IWebElement> allRows = new List<IWebElement>();
foreach(var row in GetAllCrashRows())
{
//here u gonna get each row with data inside your rows that you already have using nested element (row)
 allrows.Add(row.FindEleemnts("//div[starts-with(@class,'col h-col')]"));
}
return allRows;
}
//Then u need another foresch loop to get text with data for each inner row
public List<string> GetRowsData(){
List<string> allRowsData = new List<string>();
foreach(var data in GetAllRows())
{
 allRowsData.Add(data.Text)
}
return allRowsData;
}
```

If something is not clear let me know.